# Drupal 9 entity->url() preprocess is undefined?

Tags: drupal, entity, paragraph, drupal-9

So I am trying to create a custom banner based on user uploaded image using this
https://www.webwash.net/how-to-create-powerful-container-paragraphs-in-drupal-8/

I am using Drupal 9 and whenever I try to do this

```
 $image = $paragraph->field_image->entity->url();
```

I get this error

```
Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\file\Entity\File::url() in tm_preprocess_paragraph__main_banner()
```

I am not sure if the function changed from Drupal 8 but so far everything that works in Drupal 8 is working in Drupal 9

Answer (score 1):

aaah for anyone who faced this issue.. i literally just found the solution

in simply use createFileUrl(); instead of url()